# Wrap Type to TypeDefitinion

Tags: java, byte-buddy

How is it possible to wrap a Java Class<?> to TypeDefinition in ByteBuddy?
I have the following piece of code:

```
private TypeDefinition getFieldAndType(FieldEntry entry){
    var typeClass = String.class;

    if(entry.getModifier() == FieldModifierEnum.REPEATED){
        return TypeDescription.Generic.Builder
                .parameterizedType(ArrayList.class, typeClass).build();
        
        // Here Wrap String.class to TypeDefinition Interface?
    } return xyz;
}
```

How do I wrap "String.class" to TypeDefinition, I think there should be a way but I couldn't find it in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(...)
```

Comment: nice, that was what i was looking for :)